# How do I make grep list the count of matches before the filename?

Tags: grep

`grep -cZ` has the weird behaviour that, while filenames are nul-terminated, the count of matches appears *after* the corresponding filename. Via `od -c`:

```
0000000   /   u   s   r   /   i   n   c   l   u   d   e   /   u   c   o
0000010   n   t   e   x   t   .   h  \0   1  \n   /   u   s   r   /   i
```

This poses a peculiar problem in that I cannot directly use other commands' (such as `sort`, `sed`, etc.)  support for nul-terminated input. How do I make `grep` post the count first?

Comment: @drewbenn I'd agree that there might be other ways to do what I want to do, but this threw me off. Consider it more like a puzzle. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pipe the output to:

```
perl -pe 's/^(.*\0)(\d+)\n/$2 $1/s'
```

which will output for each match: the count, a space, the filename, \0, as requested in the comment.

Comment: Close enough. I'd swap the newline with a space, but otherwise it's fine. I'll keep the question open a little while more to see if there's more "canonical" way to do it.

Comment: @muru OK, I've modified the answer to output a space instead of a newline (this wasn't explained in the question).

Comment: Either way is fine by me, you don't need to edit.